# CFINPUT required="yes" not working with CFLOOP

Tags: coldfusion, cfml, cfloop

When I click Submit button (no data was entered) the text boxes were empty and  it still goes to the next page without popping up any messsage. It seems the cfinput required="yes" does not work the cfloop. I thought it should work even with the cfloop. I could not find what was wrong.  How can I make it work? any info is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

---

```
<cfform name="theForm" action="nextPage.cfm" method="post"> 
<table>
<tr>
<td><cfinput  type="text" name="A" size="50" required="yes message="please enter your text"></td>
</tr>

<td><cfinput  type="text" name="B" size="50" required="yes message="please enter your text"></td>
</tr>
<cfloop from=1 to=5  index=i>
</tr>
<td><cfinput  type="text" name="C" size="50" required="yes message="please enter your text"></td>
</tr>
</tr>
<td><cfinput  type="text" name="D" size="50" required="yes message="please enter your text"></td>
</tr>
</cfloop>
<tr>
<td><cfinput type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</cfform>
```

Comment: Stop using cfform and cfinout. They offer no real advantage of doing it the 'real' way.

Answer (score 2):

For this to work, you need to have unique NAMEs for each input field. Right now, you're creating a bunch of inputs named either "C" or "D". If any one "C" is filled in, then no other field named "C" needs to be filled in. Create unique names using your index variable and the validation should work as you intend.

```
<cfloop from=1 to=5  index=i>
</tr>
<td><cfinput  type="text" name="C_#i#" size="50" required="yes message="please enter your text"></td>
</tr>
</tr>
<td><cfinput  type="text" name="D_#i#" size="50" required="yes message="please enter your text"></td>
</tr>
</cfloop>
```

Comment: Yep, the `name`'s must be unique. Unfortunately, the validation scripts for textboxes can only handle a single element, not an array of same-named elements. So the routines choke and throw a syntax error. @UlalaZing - That is why the form submits without completing the validation - because an error occurred.

Comment: Confirmed. It's basically crap programming on the part of Adobe (demonstrating their developers never do web development, and just don't understand it). Another reason for not using CFFORM etc. Incidentally, Railo has the same limitation, but at least raises and exception when one runs this code.

Comment: .. or lack of programming. I do not think that particular section of the validation scripts has changed much since the Macromedia days. They could have at least added a decent error message.

Comment: Yeah, fair cop. It's broke in CFMX7 too.

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error in the `cfinput` tag

It should be

`<cfinput  type="text" name="D" size="50" required="yes" message="please enter your text">`

There is a missing quote after yes

Comment: That is probably just a copy+paste error or they would be getting a compile error.

Comment: How does one balls-up a copy and paste that much?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what was said you should use something else and not cfform if you want anything more than basic validation. The cfform stuff is really legacy and there are much better options these days.